# Differences between template class implemenations in C++ on Linux and MSVC Win32

Tags: c++, linux, templates, winapi

I'm trying to port some old Linux code to run on Windows and am running into a whole bunch of compiler errors that seem to be stemming from the considerable use of template classes.  Are there really any significant differences between how templates must be implemented for linux vs MSVC?  If so, could someone give an overview of what's actually different?  I've found lots of documentation, but nothing that actually lays down what the differences are.

Comment: You could post samples of code and errors?

Comment: This sounds like a GCC vs MSVC issue, rather than a Linux vs Windows issue.  Incidentally, there is a GCC port for Windows called MinGW: http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: If you are interested in MinGW, use the TD version at http://tdragon.net/recentgcc/

Comment: Something that might also be useful information is what version of GCC does the code compile OK with and what version of MSVC are you trying to use?

Answer (score 3):

The C++ language is defined by the C++ Standard - it isn't an operating system specific thing. How well the Standard is implemented varies from compiler to compiler, not from OS to OS.

Having said that, if it is very old code, you will probably find that the modern compilers on both Windows and Linux won't compile it. This is because these modern compilers are much stricter in their adherence to the C++ Standard, and chuck out code that earlier and less compliant compilers would have let slide.

Bottom line - you need to address each error on its own terms. Or possibly junk the code, if it is really, really old.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend **a lot** on the versions of compilers you are using both on Windows and on Linux. So I think the only way is to go through and fix the errors one by one.